# How to add the missing element to second list by comparing two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists which contain datewise data and want to add a missing data of a date in **list2** by comparing with **list1**

Lists like below

```
 list1=['2019-06-01', '2019-06-02', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05']
 list2=[['2019-06-01','3'], ['2019-06-02','0'],['2019-06-04','1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]
```

Here in **list2** doesn't contain data for **2019-06-03**, so want to add that missing data of that date to **list2** with empty values and final values of **list2** contain like below

```
list2=[['2019-06-01','3'], ['2019-06-02','0'],['2019-06-03','']['2019-06-04','1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]
```

Below is the code I'm trying with to get missing values to another list

```
 for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(list1,list2):
     if a!=b[0]:
         print a
```

which prints like below

```
  2019-06-03
  2019-06-04
  2019-06-05
```

Can somebody guide me here

Comment: could we have unsorted lists (by dates)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yea we can have now, later we can sort it by date right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one approach using `itertools.chain` and `set`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import chain

list1=['2019-06-01', '2019-06-02', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05']
list2=[['2019-06-01','3'], ['2019-06-02','0'],['2019-06-04','1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]

check_val = set(chain.from_iterable(list2))

for i in list1:
    if i not in check_val:
        list2.append([i, ""])
print(list2)
print(sorted(list2, key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

**Output:**

```
[['2019-06-01', '3'], ['2019-06-02', '0'], ['2019-06-04', '1'], ['2019-06-05', '4'], ['2019-06-03', '']]
[['2019-06-01', '3'], ['2019-06-02', '0'], ['2019-06-03', ''], ['2019-06-04', '1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]
```

Comment: Sure. `print(sorted(list2, key=lambda x: x[0]))`

Comment: Isn't `set(map(itemgetter(0), list2))` better? The way that it is is comparing with '3', '0', '1'

Comment: Not sure...probably have to test using `timeit`

Answer (score 4):

```
dates_in_list2 = [x[0] for x in list2]
missing_data = [[x, ''] for x in list1 if x not in dates_in_list2]
list2.extend(missing_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use sets to and find the [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) and add a new sublist with from the result:

```
list2 += [list(set(list1).difference([i[0] for i in list2])) + ['']]

print(list2)

[['2019-06-01', '3'],
 ['2019-06-02', '0'],
 ['2019-06-04', '1'],
 ['2019-06-05', '4'],
 ['2019-06-03', '']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not a `list` comprehension containing a generator expression:

```
print([next((x for x in list2 if v in x), [v, '']) for i, v in enumerate(list1)])
```

Output:

```
[['2019-06-01', '3'], ['2019-06-02', '0'], ['2019-06-03', ''], ['2019-06-04', '1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]
```

It keeps the order correct automatically.

Answer (score 3):

you can use set difference to find the missing dates, then add them to `list2` (and sort it by date...).

try this:

```py
list1 = ['2019-06-01', '2019-06-02', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05']
list2 = [['2019-06-01', '3'], ['2019-06-02', '0'], ['2019-06-04', '1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]

set1 = {*list1}
set2 = {t[0] for t in list2}

diff = set1 - set2

for date in diff:
    list2.append([date, ''])

list2.sort(key=lambda t: t[0])
print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[['2019-06-01', '3'], ['2019-06-02', '0'], ['2019-06-03', ''], ['2019-06-04', '1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do is for each element in `list1` iterate over `list2` and see if there is a matching element. Considering that your lists are small this shouldn't be a performance issue. If you know that your lists are sorted then you can make some optimizations but that might be an overkill for now.

Answer (score 2):

Another `set` difference within a single pipeline:

```
list2.extend([i, ''] for i in set(list1) - set(d[0] for d in list2))
list2.sort()
print(list2)
```

The output:

```
[['2019-06-01', '3'], ['2019-06-02', '0'], ['2019-06-03', ''], ['2019-06-04', '1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]
```

Answer (score 2):

I will use numpy setdiff1d function then append each item to list2.

```
import numpy as np
list1=['2019-06-01', '2019-06-02', '2019-06-03', '2019-06-04', '2019-06-05']
list2=[['2019-06-01','3'], ['2019-06-02','0'],['2019-06-04','1'], ['2019-06-05', '4']]
diff=np.setdiff1d(list1, [b[0] for b in list2])
for i in diff:
    list2.append([i,''])
list2.sort()
Result:
[['2019-06-01', '3'],
 ['2019-06-02', '0'],
 ['2019-06-04', '1'],
 ['2019-06-05', '4'],
 ['2019-06-03', '']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a dictionary constructor.  Because the constructor overrides values of duplicate keys, you can provide it with the two lists and let it prioritize list2 over list1 (with its default value):

```
result = sorted(dict((a[0],a[1:] or ["x"]) for a in list1+list2).values(),key=tuple)
```

*Note: you only have to use sorted() if you need to preserve the order*

If list1 always contains all possible dates, you could use a dictionary of list2 data as an override over default values:

```
result = [[d,v.get(d,"x")] for v in [dict(list2)] for d in list1]
```

*Note: this preserves the order and is faster than the other approach but requires list1's dates to  be a superset of list2's*